# Logged objects in chrome change in a console row?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When you log an object in the chrome console, and it is quite big, you have the nice option to unfold it.

Initially, the single line that contains the objects keys, is displayed for the contents of that object in that moment of logging. Here, we only have keys a to l

[image: console log]

If the object changes afterwards, like adding key m, the dropdown information changes, but the single line stays the same.

[image]

You can see it happen in this simple fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lj5naa2c/

```
var c;
c = {
  a: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  b: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  c: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  d: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  e: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  f: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  g: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  h: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  i: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  j: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  k: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  l: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}
console.log(c)
console.log(c.m)
c.m = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Actually, this caused some headaches here. Is this the way it is intended?
The single line never updates when the object updates, so we were confused why we saw an undefined after logging the object but when we looked at it, it was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional. The little information bubble beside the initial log details why this occurs. The object shown in the log is a snapshot during log. Then the dropdown is evaluated at the time it is requested. So if something changes before you do a dropdown, then that is going to be reflected there instead of the data at log time.

[image: tooltip data]